# How to know what is still running in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to Scala and has already learned to use `sbt run` (or `run` within sbt shell) to run my simple program.

Now, my problem is that when I run the program, the execution doesn't end. My last line of a simple "main" is reached, but the application continues to run. And the control doesn't return to shell.

**How do I know what is still running** in my sbt-controlled application?

I am playing with play-ws asynchronous HTTP clients, so I suspect there are some threads waiting for something. But how to know what and why?

I know I can terminate it whole with `Ctrl+C`, but that doesn't help me to understand what has leaked.

Comment: I still don't know how to do it. But in this particular case it turned out to be me not calling `shutdown` on an `akka.actor.ActorSystem` instance.

Comment: It looks like logical error in your program. Did you try to Ctr+Z ? Force sbt to terminate, kill sbt process, review you app. Check if there is no ghost process under sbt,. this could cause sbt problems to run one more time. Use kill command as well as ps commends to see what you have in the memory.

Comment: Try sending a `SIQQUIT` to the program (`Ctrl+\ `). Alternately, use `jps` to view a thread dump.